# 'disabled' CSS property not working with Semantic UI override with Styled-Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hello all and thank you for your help! I am currently trying to edit the disabled property that is available from the Semantic UI Library. The component is `Menu` component. This disabled property is on the `Menu` children such as `Menu.Item`.

I am also using Styled-Components library to write the CSS. I am grabbing the `Menu.Item` and adding styles to it. When I target the disabled property it won't update. I want to be able to have it be a light gray background then when active show up with the previous styling that is dynamically applied.

React Component

```
import React from "react";
import { CustomMenuItem } from "./StyledElements/MenuItemElements";

const StyledMenuItem = (props) => {

  return <CustomMenuItem {...props} />;
};

export default StyledMenuItem;
}

export default StyledDropdownItem
```

Styled component Styling

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Menu } from "semantic-ui-react";

export const CustomMenuItem = styled(Menu.Item)`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemColor};

  /* Running 4 & signs to override bg color and the hover effect from semantic */
  &&&& {
    background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemBGColor};
    border: 0.25px solid ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemBorderLeftRightColor};
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;

    &[aria-disabled="true"] {
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemNotActiveColor} !important;
      background: ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemNotActiveBGColor} !important;
    }

    &:disabled {
      color: ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemNotActiveColor} !important;
      background: ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemNotActiveBGColor} !important;
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.menuItemBGHover};
    }
  }
`;
```

Actual component being used

```
<StyledMenuItem className='scheduleEditorButton' size='tiny' disabled={!shouldUndo} title='Undo'>
     <StyledIcon name='undo' /> // Irrelevant
     <StyledHeaderText as="p" content="Undo"/> // Irrelevant
</StyledMenuItem>
```

I am not sure If I am doing this right or not. I have searched a lot of places and still haven't been able to figure it out. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You should try `&[aria-disabled="true"]` instead of `&:disabled {` as they are using aria attributes.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I went ahead and gave that a shot and unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: That's strange because both `&[aria-disabled="true"]` and `&.disabled` worked for me. Could you post the whole dropdown component?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I just re-edited the original post with the changes you mentioned.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I apologize I was linking the wrong components but I tested both and it still didn't work. The updated post has the current information.